# Different behaviour for onActivityResult in DialogFragment in Android O

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, onactivityresult, android-8.0-oreo

I've noticed a difference between Android 7 (and before) and Android 8 (beta) when calling `startActivityForResult` from a `DialogFragment`.

In `MainActivity` below, when 'OK' is pressed on the dialog, it dismisses itself, creates and shows a new dialog, and calls `startActivityForResult` for `AnotherActivity`. `AnotherActivity` immediately finishes.

On Android 7, `onActivityResult` is called on the new dialog instance. On Android 8, `onActivityResult` is never called.

Can anyone explain this difference?

**MCVE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "tag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new SomeDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }

    public static class SomeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
    {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setPositiveButton(
                    "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which)
                        {
                            dismiss();
                            SomeDialogFragment dialog = new SomeDialogFragment();
                            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_TAG);
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class), 7);
                        }
                    });

            return builder.create();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            // Called on Android 7 but not Android 8.
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setResult(1);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a call to `setResult`?, they might've made `resultCode` undefined unless a result is actually set.

Comment: Whether or not you called `setResult` makes no difference. I removed it to make the MCVE more minimal.

Comment: Does it work on ANdroid 7?

Comment: Yes it does. I'll update my question.